# Initial backbone.js data fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been playing with backbone.js for the last few days, editing the Todos example and writing my own version.

I'm now looking at creating a controller with multiple routes, but what I have found after following the Todos example is calling the `Todos.fetch()`, causes the items to be re-rendered. I think its calling the refresh event?

The backbone.js documentation says:

> Note that fetch should not be used to populate collections on page load — all models needed at load time should already be bootstrapped into place. fetch is intended for lazily-loading models for interfaces that are not needed immediately: for example, documents with collections of notes that may be toggled open and closed.

What is the best way to load data then? Can I use an use an ajax call to get the data and pass it when instantiating the main controller?
What about if I were to change page and a new view were to shown? Would I just call the `fetch()` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bit of documentation is there to remind you that you should load all the data on the initial page load and use fetch for all the subsequent loads.

You can have code like this:

```
MyCollection = new Collection({some json data});
```

Much faster than a page load then a couple of request to load the data.

Comment: Thanks, I assume that this would be in the controller initialize?

Comment: In script tag on the initial page.

Comment: Would you then pass the data to the controller? Does it not make more sense to put it in the init within the controller?

Comment: Your controller would be in a ".js" file. So I would not suggest to load dynamic json data in it (depends on the page, user, etc.). Create the collection on your page and instantiate a controller and give the collection as an argument.

Comment: I wish this answer were a little more specific. What exactly does some json data mean here?

Comment: @Incodeveritas "some json data" is an array of models , that you have already on your page , probably in a form of a script that was processed by your backend. Or it can be any `model` data that you want to use for `bootstraping` the app.

Answer (score 3):

Im a bit confused on the wording of the doc as well, but fetch is the way to tell your **Collection** or **Model** to go the server and get the data via either your own sync function or **Backbone.sync** which already internally uses ajax and can pass the result along to your success or error function.

As far as Todos example you mentioned, thats how **Collection** is meant to work. It updates the models, then triggers 'refresh' event which may force your view to be re-rendered, like you said.

I highly recommend looking at Backbone.js code. Its very effectively documented and the flow of events and method calls is very easy to grasp due to that.

Comment: I think after looking at other code as well as Juliens answer need to do my own AJAX call in my initial controller.

Comment: Is that what you end up doing after all..did you come across anything better... I would imagine backbone would specify some method to do it even its just an ajax call only...I'm in the same situation now